# Setting up a connection to an external webservice with authentication

Tags: callout, apexrest, authentication, external-services

I'm new to authentication an I have some questions. The office wants me to create an 'internal user context', so the users of Salesforce can load data out of an external database.

I need to set up an HttpRequest with authentication from Salesforce to the database. In the database which I configure as a web service I need to create the authentication context, but how does this context know when to give access and when not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further as -- are you asking how would your webservice know who is invoking the services and how will they provide the necessary access?

Comment: Exactly, sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: That needs to be taken care by your service provider. From Salesforce you just want to make sure that you pass the details as required by the service viz., username, password, any other parameters. Now, how and what level of access your service provides will depend on your service provider implementation. If you are looking for how to invoke webservices from Salesforce, this [**link**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts.htm) will provide you with all required details.

Comment: Yes this documentation is useful.. Allright let's say we require only password and username. We configure it in our service provider, but if you're invoking the callout and pass the credentials. How does the service provider know this is a correct user with password?

Comment: A username and password will be provided by your service provider if the service is supposed to be authenticated. And it's again the responsibility of your service provider to verify the credentials, nothing from Salesforce side again. Your question is more towards the service provider side, so you should try to see how have they implemented the authentication and that what details you need from them to invoke the services.

Comment: Yeah this is maybe more to the service provider, well allright thanks for your answers